# Meaning of verbのに向かって

Tags: meaning

I'm having trouble understanding the meaning of のに向かって in the following sentence:

> 現れたのは、いつになく暗い表情をした１年生メンバーの真姫{まき}でした。笑顔の穂乃果{ほのか}が早く列に入るように目線でうながす**のに向かって**、大きく首を横に振ると、大げさな溜息をひとつつきます。

I know that に向かって normally means something like "towards", but I can't figure out what that would mean with a verb.

Comment: It is のに　and 向かって、not に向かって。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「～～に向かって 」, in this context, means "***in response to ~~***".

The 「の」, of course, is a nominalizer. turning the verb phrase 「目線でうながす」 into a noun.

> "in response to Honoka urging me with her eyes to get in the line quickly"